# Utilizando barcodelib

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

Trabajo en app de Windows Forms, [BarcodeLib](https://github.com/barnhill/barcodelib)

Lo implemento de la siguiente manera.

```
var b = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
        System.Drawing.Image img = b.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE39, "2001201901070202304500110011000000000161234567819", Color.Black, Color.White, 400, 100);
        var pathBarCode = Application.StartupPath + "\\myBarCode.png";
        img.Save(pathBarCode);
```

Me da error en la segunda linea:

```
EGENERATE_IMAGE-2: Image size specified not large enough to draw image. 
(Bar size determined to be less than 1 pixel)
```

Ya he modificado el largo de la imagen pero me sigue dando el mismo error.
¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Prueba con las misma dimensiones es decir 400 x 400

Comment: Se soluciono poniendo `System.Drawing.Image img = b.Encode(TYPE.CODE39, "2001201901070202304500110011000000000161234567819", Color.Black, Color.White, 1000, 200);`

Comment: Sip es que tu texto es muy largo

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez No lo sabía muchas gracias.